# Page not found (404) Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:4000/person/persondetails/3

Tags: python, django, django-views

A person list is displayed perfectly in `person.html`, but when I click the  `persondetails` anchor tag I'm getting an error.  Please let me know how to rectify this.

- Project `urls.py`

  ```
  from django.conf.urls import url, 
  include from django.contrib import admin

  urlpatterns = [    
          url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),    
          url(r'^',include('example.urls')), 
  ]
  ```
- app `urls.py`

  ```
  from django.conf.urls import url
  from . import views
  urlpatterns = [
      url(r'^$', views.HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
      url(r'^about/$', views.AboutPageView.as_view(), name='about'),
      url(r'^data/$', views.DataPageView.as_view(), name='data'),
      url(r'^person/$', views.PersonPageView.as_view(), name='person'),
      url(r'^persondetails/(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$', 
         views.PersonDetailPageView.as_view(), name='persondetails'),
     ]
  ```
- `views.py`

  ```
  class PersonDetailPageView(DetailView):
      def details(self,pk):
         personDetail=get_object_or_404(Person, pk=self.kwargs.get("pk"))

         return redirect(request,'example/persondetails.html',          
        {'personDetail':personDetail})
  ```
- `person.html`

  ```
   <tbody>
        {% for persons  in person  %}
            <tr>
                <td><a href="persondetails/{{persons.pk}}"> 
                                 {{persons.first_name}}</a></td>
                <td><a href="persondetails/{{persons.pk}}"> 
            {{persons.first_name}}</a></td>
                <td>{{persons.last_name}}</td>
                <td>{{persons.email}}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  ```

Comment: from django.conf.urls import url, 
include from django.contrib import admin should be two lines - include should be on the first line and the second line should start with "include from django.contrib..."

Comment: url(r'^persondetails/(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/$' ...   would probably be better as: 
 url(r'^persondetails/(?P<pk>\d+)/$' ...

Comment: The url in the error message looks like it could be a problem:  /person/persondetails/3.  It contains both "person" and "persondetails", but I don't see a url pattern containing both together like that - your urls.py only defines "person/" and "persondetails/".

Answer (score 0):

In your urls.py, you have added, `persondetails/pk..` hence it will redirect you to the url e.g. for id 3,

```
http://127.0.0.1:4000/persondetails/3/
```

You can add it in ..person/persondetail/pk...

For better arrangement, 
views.py,

```
class PersonDetailPageView(DetailView):
     model = Your_Model_Name
     template_name = 'your_template_name.html'
```

In html,

```
<a href="{% url 'persondetails' person.id %}"> your template </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Bidhan i changed my code above mention way. getting below errror.

Page not found (404)
 Request Method:    GET
 Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:4000/persondetails/1/
 Using the URLconf defined in djangotemplates.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in 
 this order:

```
^admin/
^ ^$ [name='home']
^ ^about/$ [name='about']
^ ^data/$ [name='data']
^ ^person/$ [name='person']
^ ^person/persondetails/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$ [name='persondetails']
```

The current path, persondetails/1/, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.